# Redis stream that should be consumed by all clients

Tags: api, redis, stream, consumer

I am new to Redis. I have a use case that a Redis stream shall be consumed by every member of a group of clients. However, currently the concept of consumer group in Redis stream means a message shall be consumed *only once* by any of the client in the group.

Does Redis stream has built in support for this particular use case?
Thank you

---Patrick

Comment: Do you still need to ACK each message by every consumer? If you don't then just don't use consumer groups and if you do you can create a group per consumer

Comment: No.
But shall I use one channel or multiple channels?

Comment: One channel should do

Comment: Thank you. So a stream can be thought of as a File. One process write, many other processes can read in the same time , and each of them will have their internal pointers to keep track the reading positions.

Comment: you can do that with Streams, BTW you are not limited to a single writer